# Is it possible to perform operations individually to faces?

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms, selection-tools, topology

I would like to know if it is possible to perform operations (extrude and scale mainly) to *individual* faces as opposed to groups of faces.

Currently when I select these faces...

[image]

And extrude, I get this:

[image]

I would like to know how to get this:

[image]

Setting the pivot point to *Individual Origins* doesn't work either for contiguous selections of faces.

[image]

[image]

I often need to do this kind of extrude+scale to lots of faces at a time, so it is simply not efficient (bordering on impossible) to do them one at a time as I did for the example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>*> Individual faces* to do this:

[image]

There is also a button in the tool shelf under *Tools > Mesh Tools > Add*:

[image]

Comment: ALT+S just does a regular scale it seems, they faces are not separated.

Comment: @leigero Alt+S actually does a [shrink-fatten](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/deforming/shrink-fatten.html?highlight=shrink). To do an "individual scale", [set the pivot point to individual](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/pivot_point/individual_origins.html#in-edit-mode) and then scale normally (S).

Answer (score 4):

you can also use the **[Inset Faces](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Duplicating/Inset)** tool by pressing <kbd>I</kbd> (or pressing thespace bar and typing Inset)

[image]

, and selecting **Individual faces** as option.

[image]

Comment: Note that you can also select it by pressing I twice, and depth can be controlled with `Ctrl`+ mouse movement.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Individual Origins as pivot point]

You can select Individual Origins to set each face's center as the center rather than the bounding box center of all faces combined

Answer (score 0):

And you can always select faces one by one and extrude each one of them separately. Extrude individual extrudes each face along its normal, so the result depends on the surface of your model. Try it with a uv sphere.