# Chocolate bar making

Tags: modeling, mesh

Below you see the chocolate bar I made. The method I used is that, I created a cube, made its size as rectangle and extrude top a little, resize then extrude again. And there was one part of chocolate bar. After that I duplicated it and joined them together to made the final chocolate bar. But is there a way to duplicate the action I do on one face when I work on subdivision? That would make this kind of work so much easier.
[image: my_chocolate_bar_experiment]

Comment: Using duplicate linked (ALT D) helps a lot , but maybe not modifiers, it seems they are still applied per object...

Comment: now i worked on it again i tried to apply mirror modifier and it works on all subdivisions. interesting that i could not that get working at first try, i'm still learning. Thanks for comment.

Comment: in this particular case you could also try arrays...

Comment: so if i understand correct, that i will made one part of this bar ready and use array modifier to apply the rest? I will try that too, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question 100% correctly. So forgive me if I answer not what've asked.

Straight to *"is there a way to duplicate the action...?"*
<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> is your friend when you've just done something good to a face (edge, vert, multiple selection...) and would like to do the same to others. Just select the next part and hit the shortcut. Big time-saver indeed.

And as the topic suggests let me give you my advice on actual chocolate bar design (who can stand tempted with chocolate :-)).

As suggested by **m.ardito** you could go with arrays too.
But my favourite for this kind of models is *cube-modelling* + *edge-loops* + *inset faces*. Very quick, in fact.
Don't forget to choose *Individual* for **Inset faces** and play with *Depth* (hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>). Then adjust by scaling on separate axes with *Individual origins* as pivots.

[image: chocolate bar]

With this I really wanted to demonstrate that you don't necessarily need to repeat some action if your model is *by-nature* very homogenous.

Comment: that was exactly what i wanted to learn. thanks a lot, i also find my answer in different topic at http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/16262/24049 this. Again thanks a lot.